# Spring repository injection does not work

Tags: spring-data-jpa, wildfly

I'm writing a test Spring application with maven that use Spring Data. When I deploy it on wildfly 18 an error occur because dependency injection does not work:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<test.model.Utenti, Integer> {

}

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

the error is:

```
09:54:47,345 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'test.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I'm using Sping 4.3.26.RELEASE, Spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, MySQL connector version 8.0.18 with Java 1.8.

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml

Comment: When I add pom.xml I receive error message: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Try to add it as plain text and not as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below if you've not to your Main Class.

```
@ComponentScan("test")
```

## Update

Add the below in `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=<URL>
spring.datasource.username=<USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password=<Password>
spring.jpa.database=<Database for example POSTGRESQL>
spring.jpa.database-platform=<Dialect e.g. org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect>
```

Comment: I've already added the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test")` annotation.

Comment: Is it necessary to configure a datasource with Spring Data obviously, how should I configure it?

Comment: Is this a SpringBoot application or Plain Spring?

Comment: I followed the example of the following address: `https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/` and the error that I receive when I deploy now is: `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in test.HelloWorldConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;`